# how to modify pod memory limit of a running pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

I am using YML to create pod and have specified the resource request and limit. Now I am not aware of how to modify the resource limits of a running pod. For example

memory-demo.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: memory-demo
  namespace: mem-example
spec:
  containers:
  - name: memory-demo-ctr
    image: polinux/stress
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "200Mi"
      requests:
        memory: "100Mi"
    command: ["stress"]
    args: ["--vm", "1", "--vm-bytes", "150M", "--vm-hang", "1"]
```

Then I run the command `oc create -f memory-demo.yml` and a pod name memory-demo get created.

My Question is what should I do to modify the memory limits from `200Mi  --> 600 Mi`, Do I need to delete the existing pod and recreate the pod using the modified YML file?

I am a total newbie. Need help.

Comment: Is it even possible to make such a change on a running pod? I have access to both `web console` and CLI.

Comment: Pods are immutable, so whatever changes you apply via the Pods API will be ignored after the pod is created.  See the answer on using a Deployment to manage the recreation of Pods as your desires for said pods change.

Comment: Thank you `ctt`. This information is helpful. I was not aware of the immutability concept for the pod.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First and for most, it is very unlikely that you really want to be (re)creating Pods directly. Dig into what [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) is and how it works. Then you can simply apply the change to the spec template in deployment and kubernetes will upgrade all the pods in that deployment to match new spec in a hands free rolling update.

Live change of the memory limit for a running container is certainly possible but not by means of kubernetes (and will not be reflected in kube state if you do so). Look at [docker update](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/).

Comment: Thanks Radek 'Goblin' Pieczonka. I'll try creating the pod using deployment. But in my case, i just wanted to know that if a pod was created directly using `oc create -f <file.yml>` then what can be done to update the memeory limits specs. As aove `ctt` replied that pods are immutable and whatever chage we apply via Pods API will be ignored after the pod is created. 
I was just curious to know how these changes will be rolled out using the Deployment, means Does deployment will make specs change to live running pod or it will also recreate the pod with new specs?

Comment: It will delete old pods and create new ones adhering to new spec.

Comment: You'll soon be able to update pod resources in-place, see
https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/1287

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace` command to modify an existing object based on the contents of the specified configuration file ([documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/cli_reference/basic_cli_operations.html#replace))

```
oc replace -f memory-demo.yml
```

EDIT: However, some spec can not be update. The only way is delete and re-create the pod.

Comment: Hi Thanks hgiasac, 

I tried to `oc replace -f <yml.file>` command and i am getting error `The Pod "memory-consumer" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than `containers[*].image` or `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Some spec can not be update. The only way is delete and re-create the pod.

Comment: You'll soon be able to update pod resources in-place, see
https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/1287